# How to write firestore batch in react-redux-firebase

Tags: react-redux-firebase

In react-redux-firebase, how do I do a batch write similar to that shown in the firestore docs? (see below)

```
// Get a new write batch
var batch = db.batch();

// Set the value of 'NYC'
var nycRef = db.collection("cities").doc("NYC");
batch.set(nycRef, {name: "New York City"});

// Update the population of 'SF'
var sfRef = db.collection("cities").doc("SF");
batch.update(sfRef, {"population": 1000000});

// Delete the city 'LA'
var laRef = db.collection("cities").doc("LA");
batch.delete(laRef);

// Commit the batch
batch.commit().then(function () {
    // ...
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Something like this would work. Don't forget that `react-redux-firebase` and `redux-firestore` extend the original implementations of `firebase` and `firestore` respectively.

```js
const Counter = () => {
  const firestore = useFirestore()
  const batch = firestore.batch()
  const nycRef = firestore.get({collection: 'cities', doc: 'NYC'})
  batch.set(nycRef, {name: 'New York City'})
  const sfRef = firestore.get({collection: 'cities', doc: 'SF'})
  batch.update(sfRef, {population: 10000000})
  const laRef = firestore.get({collection: 'cities', doc: 'LA'})
  firestore.delete(laRef)
  const runBatch = async () => await batch.commit()

  return <button onClick={runBatch}>Attempt Batch</button>
}
```

Comment: `const firestore = useFirestore(); const batch = firestore.batch();` unfortunately I get the typescript error => Property 'batch' does not exist on type 'ExtendedFirestoreInstance'. Any Ideas?

Comment: You can see that the method is added [here](https://github.com/prescottprue/redux-firestore/blob/80509370c681c2bd848f7185aec30d0d0d28fe50/src/constants.js#L134) and [here](https://github.com/prescottprue/redux-firestore/blob/80509370c681c2bd848f7185aec30d0d0d28fe50/src/createFirestoreInstance.js#L43).

Try adding a `@ts-expect-error` above `const batch = firestore.batch()` and see if the Javascript works. I have had it working before so I know it is possible. I am just unable to check how at the moment.